# Prop.test with Multiple Imputation

Tags: r, proportion, multiple-imputation

I have a large dataset with a large amount of missing data, so I used the `mice` package to create multiple imputations to fill in the missing values.
Now I am trying to perform `prop.test()` and `pairwise.prop.test()` with the new data, but I keep getting an error on the second and third line of code (creating the table is fine).

```
prop.test1 <- with(df, table(AvgGrade, Work_Status))
with(df, prop.test(prop.test1))
prop.test(pool(prop.test1))
```

> Error in prop.test(prop.test1) : argument "n" is missing, with no default

Is there a way to perform the `prop.test()` function with a multiple imputation?

Comment: I don't think multiple imputation will be useful in such bivariate setting.

Comment: @MichaelM if multiple imputations are not necessary for bivariate analysis, then is it justified to analyze some of your data using MI (e.g., linear regressions) and some using complete case (e.g., probability testing)?

Comment: Yes, this seems justified. (I don't know the full context though.)

Comment: Thank you @MichaelM. What would you need for better context? I cant share information on the data itself, but I can explain the current situation or reasonings depending on how the context would help